# PHP で url のパラメータから特定の key に対応する値を抽出したい

Tags: php

https://www.google.co.jp/imgres?imgurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/img/lineup_img_03.png&imgrefurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/&h=294&w=300&tbnid=hii2NgfRdpdAWM:&docid=6SI3d_RhJqENlM&ei=bRXIVvSuNOasmAXEv6H4BQ&tbm=isch

上記のURLで、keyのimgurl（https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/img/lineup_img_03.png）だけ取得するにはどのようにすれば宜しいでしょうか。
言語はphpで行いたいと考えています。
詳しい方ご教示下さい。

Answer (score 6):

URLを文字列として解析(parse)したいのであれば、「php URL parse」辺りで検索をかければいろいろ実例付きの解説記事が見つかるかと思いますが、[parse_url()関数](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.parse-url.php)と[parse_str()関数](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.parse-str.php)を組み合わせるのが常道だろうと思います。

```
$url_string = 'https://www.google.co.jp/imgres?imgurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/img/lineup_img_03.png&imgrefurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/&h=294&w=300&tbnid=hii2NgfRdpdAWM:&docid=6SI3d_RhJqENlM&ei=bRXIVvSuNOasmAXEv6H4BQ&tbm=isch';
$query = parse_url($url_string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $query_array);
echo $query_array['imgurl']; //->https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/img/lineup_img_03.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//対象のURL
$gs_url = "https://www.google.co.jp/imgres?imgurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/img/lineup_img_03.png&imgrefurl=https://www.irobot-jp.com/roomba/800series/&h=294&w=300&tbnid=hii2NgfRdpdAWM:&docid=6SI3d_RhJqENlM&ei=bRXIVvSuNOasmAXEv6H4BQ&tbm=isch";
//正規表現パターン：imgurl～のURL
$pattern = '/.*?imgurl=(http.*?.png|http.*?.jpg|http.*?.jpeg|http.*?.gif).*?/';

preg_match($pattern, $gs_url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

echo $matches[1][0];
?>
```